# can a guy with embedded system background go into game development

Tags: game-design

Well, I finished my Masters in Embedded Systems, and I am working in GUI development, and working with graphic tools and images and GUI's keep me glued to my seat more than working on code for MUP/MUC . And I want to give game development a Fair chance, try out developing a game from scratch using basic libraries then tryout the same in a free/open source game engine and there is a good chance I may fall in love with it, but it is poissible for a person with an Electrical and Electronics Bachelors and Embedded Systems Masters ( just a years experience in the field) go into game development and be successful in the profession.

And I asked the same question @ stackoverflow.com (wrong place to ask )
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794822/can-a-guy-with-embedded-system-background-go-into-game-development/13794943#13794943

And I received good but a very generic answer. I would be happy to know the actual pro's and con's of a master's in embedded systems migrating to Game Dev

And I am extremely sorry for asking the same question for the third time but I really did not know that stackoverflow had so many sister sites, So a really big sorry, and an even bigger thank you!

Comment: *And* you asked [the same question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/178899/3688) a third time on programmers.se, too. Impatient, much?

Comment: I apologized for that, and I am sorry for being Impatient too. Even though, thank you for having the patience to read my question thrice and still being polite.

Comment: I think his question is directed more towards entering the industry, not just making it for fun and laughs. And how his existing expertise can benefit him.

Comment: Yeah, it is towards entering the Industry, I want to do what I like very much 24x7, as of now I work, but i dont enjoy my work, so I am serious about entering the Industry Mr. Cardin, I am sorry if my auestion was not direct enough, but that was my intention in asking this question

Answer (score 1):

> No, you can't make a game.
>
> My logic is this:  if you could make a game, you'd be too busy making
>   a game for you to want to waste your time by posting a question asking
>   strangers on the internet whether or not you can make a game. 
>   Therefore, by process of elimination, you must not be able to make a
>   game.

If you want to make a game, that's great -- do it!  I can highly recommend game making as a rewarding creative outlet.  But asking other people whether it's going to be possible for you is just pointless procrastination.  And you're not going to finish a game by procrastinating.

So my advice for a happy and successful life:  less asking for permission from internet strangers.  More actually doing the things you want to do.

Comment: `less asking for permission from internet strangers. More actually doing the things you want to do.` I was tempted to downvote this question for exactly this reason.

Comment: Yes Mr.Trevor your absolutely right, but I was not trying to procrastinate, I came across the followig article http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/creative/game-design/how-to-build-a-game-in-a-week-from-scratch-with-no-budget-r2259 while I was searching for info on Game Engine's and well I like what the author did and would like to start of from the basics but I lack any skill in OOPS and I am very Procedural since I dwell in Assembly and C, and my recent GUI programming is the only sniff i got of OOPS thats why I sought Expert opinion, But still you are right about me wasting time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, yes, and yes.  I work on embedded stuff during the day and games at night for fun.  Your background can give you some advantages.  For example, you're used to writing code that has to meet tight timing deadlines within very limited resources.  Also, you should be able to pick up GPU programming, since you've worked with similar hardware.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

As an embedded engineer you have some coding experience that is surely beneficial in terms of solving challenging design scenarios in game development. However, you would also need to brush up more on OOP languages as well as familiarise yourself with the tools and assets that a game programmer would have to interface with in code.

I highly suggest you try to design and code a simple but interesting game, and see if it's really something you'd enjoy doing. And it'd be good for portfolio, i think?

just my two cents as an EE engineer hobbying in game dev.